# Check if heapq contains value

Tags: python, queue, priority-queue

I am using the heapq object to store objects of class which I implemented.

```
import heapq

heap = []
element1 = Element('A', 1)
element2 = Element('B', 2)
element3 = Element('C', 3)
heapq.heappush(heap, element1)
heapq.heappush(heap, element2)
heapq.heappush(heap, element3)
```

In my class Element I overwrite method `__cmp__` to ensure that value is the priority

```
def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.value, other.value)
```

Now I want to write a function, which checks if heap contains element, such that
if I want to check if `element = Element('A', 1)` is in the heap, the answer will be `True`, if I will check `element = Element('A',100)` the answer will be also `True`, but if I want to check `element = Element('D',1)` the answer will be `False`.
How can I implement such method? Is it possible to check elements of `heapq` without calling `pop()` method?

Comment: Is `Element` just a wrapper for values and their priorities used only for this heap, or do you have to use this class for other reasons?

Comment: can you add a bit more info as to what this class is actually for and is this for python 2 or 3?

Comment: @tobias_k I have to use this class for other reasons

Comment: @Ziva In this case, you could take particular care that implementing `eq` and `cmp` in an inconsistent way does not cause problems in other places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the method `__eq__` in `Element` so you can check for membership using the keyword `in` (without `__eq__` the code `Element('A', 1) == Element('A', 1)` would give `False`):

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.key == other.key
```

Heaps are just lists in python, so just use the following and `__eq__` will do the rest:

```
Element('A', 1) in heap
```

### Example

```
import heapq

heap = []
element1 = Element('A', 1)
element2 = Element('B', 2)
element3 = Element('C', 3)
heapq.heappush(heap, element1)
heapq.heappush(heap, element2)
heapq.heappush(heap, element3)

print Element('A', 1) in heap      # True
print Element('A', 100) in heap    # True
print Element('D', 1) in heap      # False
```

Comment: I think `__eq__` should compare only the `key`, so that `(A, 1)` == `(A, 100)`

Comment: @tobias_k It's possible, but maybe he wants to allow duplicates, it depends on the semantic. Let's see what the OP says and I'll adapt the code if needed. Thanks for the observation!

Comment: I think it's pretty clear: "if I will check element = Element('A',100) the answer will be also True"

Comment: Doesn't `Element('A', 1) in heap` operate in `O(n)` time? A sorted binary tree should be searchable in `O(log n)` time. I was hoping to find a way to do this with the benefit of the `heapq` sorting. Unless I'm missing something? I think this SO post answers this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619369/find-the-position-of-an-element-in-a-heap

Answer (score 3):

The [solution by @enrico](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25316839/1639625) works, implementing `__eq__` to check whether elements are in the heap, and `__cmp__` for prioritizing the elements. However, it will produce some strange side effects. For example, `Element('A', 1)` will at the same time be `==` to and `<` than `Element('A', 2)`.

Alternatively, you could just use regular `tuples` instead of that `Element` wrapper class. With the number in the first place, the tuples natural ordering will suffice for the heap, and for checking whether some element is in the heap, you could `zip` the items to get a list of the actual keys (in your example: the letters) or use `any`.

```
heap = []
heapq.heappush(heap, (1, 'A'))
heapq.heappush(heap, (3, 'C'))
heapq.heappush(heap, (2, 'B'))

print('A' in zip(*heap)[1])
print(any('D' == b for a, b in heap)
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Note, however, that (just like using `__eq__` and `in`) this will in the worst case (the element is not in the heap) test each element in the heap, which, if this is used in sort of a priority-queue setting, will ruin the otherwise O(log n) performance of the heap. Instead, you might want to use another `set` or `dict` besides the heap to store and look up elements that have already been handled (and their corresponding result) and/or are currently in the heap.